# Dart - How to set the hour and minute of DateTime object

Tags: android, dart, flutter

How do I set/change the hour and/or minute of a DateTime object. Similar to `Date.setHours(..)` in JavaScript.

e.g If i did

```
var time = DateTime.parse("2018-08-16T11:00:00.000Z");
```

how do I set the hour and minute of `time`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
var newHour = 5;
time = time.toLocal();
time = new DateTime(time.year, time.month, time.day, newHour, time.minute, time.second, time.millisecond, time.microsecond);
```

There were discussions to add an `update()` method that allows to modify specific parts only, but it doesn't look like this has landed.

Comment: Thanks, but this is what i was already doing. Was looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: There was some work being done, but it didn't make it into the SDK yet https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/pull/24646. You can create a convenience function yourself to make such things easier if you need it often.

Comment: Another way to change date - time.add(Duration(hours: 2, minutes: 30)), but I doubt that it is solution. I don't know another methods to change DateTime

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky it depends on what you want. Adding/removing duration can have surprising effects when it hits daylight saving boundaries.

Answer (score 42):

now with extension u could do something like this

```
extension MyDateUtils on DateTime {
  DateTime copyWith({
    int? year,
    int? month,
    int? day,
    int? hour,
    int? minute,
    int? second,
    int? millisecond,
    int? microsecond,
  }) {
    return DateTime(
      year ?? this.year,
      month ?? this.month,
      day ?? this.day,
      hour ?? this.hour,
      minute ?? this.minute,
      second ?? this.second,
      millisecond ?? this.millisecond,
      microsecond ?? this.microsecond,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how to make a variable using this?

Comment: it's used to copy ur old value with changed field:


`final newVariable = oldValue.copyWith(year: oldValue.year+1);`

Comment: the above example is correct but will not compile with null safety make sure to add a `?` after each variable type. e.g.: `int? year`

Comment: yeah, i should update it

Answer (score 19):

Since Dart 2.19.0 the `copyWith` method was added to `DateTime`, it can be used like this:

```dart
final currentTime = DateTime.now();
final twelve = currentTime.copyWith(hour: 12, minute: 0);
```

Answer (score 12):

I got a simpler solution:

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.now();
DateTime formatedDate = newDate.subtract(Duration(hours: newDate.hour, minutes: newDate.minute, seconds: newDate.second, milliseconds: newDate.millisecond, microseconds: newDate.microsecond));
```

Then the XX:XX from 'formatedDate' should be 00:00

Explanation:

formatedDate is a new DateTime variable with the content of newDate minus hours, minutes... from it

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Extension Methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) with dart to extend existing libraries.

First define your extension , by extending the DateTime Object:

```dart
extension DateTimeExt on DateTime {
  DateTime applyTimeOfDay({required int hour, required int minute}) {
      return DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute);
}
}
```

Once your new method is defined, you can call it exactly like the already defined methods of that object.

in this case, once you defined the `applyTimeOfDay()` method you can call it like so :

```dart
int myNewHour = 10
int myNewMinute = 8
var time = DateTime.parse("2018-08-16T11:00:00.000Z");
time = time.applyTimeOfDay(hour : myNewHour, minute : myNewMinute);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a better solution than the accepted answer:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ssa', 'en_US').parseLoose('01-11-2020 2:00:00AM');
```

Comment: why a method that involves parsing better?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the current hours and minutes, and then add your wanted hours and minutes.

So if you would want to set the time to for example 23:59 you could do this:

```dart
    final date = DateTime.now();
    date
      ..subtract(Duration(hours: date.hour, minutes: date.minute))
      ..add(Duration(hours: 23, minutes: 59));
```

(Note that the other time units like seconds and milliseconds aren't changed here)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by **adding or subtracting** to DateTime, using this package [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy). It also respects leap years and how many days are in each month

```
var updateTime = Jiffy.parse("2018-08-16T11:00:00.000Z").add(hours: 1); // 2018-08-16 12:00:00.000Z

print(updateTime.dateTime); // 2018-08-16 12:30:00.000Z

// also you can format it
print(updateTime.format("yyyy, MMM")); // 2018, Aug

// or use default formats
print(updateTime.yMMMEdjm); // Thu, Aug 16, 2018 12:30 PM
```

Comment: Can we round time with this package?

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues while using the formatted form of a `DateTime` object (using [`DateFormat`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)) in my widget because `showDatePicker` brought a new instance of DateTime and calling `setState` doesn't have effect on the view.

There might be better ways to comply with my problem, but I decided to create my own one which is updateable using `.update` method.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MDateTime {
  int year, month, day, hour, min, sec;

  factory MDateTime.fromDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
    return MDateTime(
      dateTime.year,
      dateTime.month,
      dateTime.day,
      dateTime.hour,
      dateTime.minute,
      dateTime.second,
    );
  }

  MDateTime([
    this.year = 0,
    this.month = 0,
    this.day = 0,
    this.hour = 0,
    this.min = 0,
    this.sec = 0,
  ]);

  void update({
    int? newYear,
    int? newMonth,
    int? newDay,
    int? newHour,
    int? newMin,
    int? newSec,
  }) {
    year = newYear ?? year;
    month = newMonth ?? month;
    day = newDay ?? day;
    hour = newHour ?? hour;
    min = newMin ?? min;
    sec = newSec ?? sec;
  }

  DateTime toDateTime() {
    return DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);
  }

  TimeOfDay toTimeOfDay() {
    return TimeOfDay(hour :hour, minute:  min);
  }

  String formatDate({String divider = "-"}){
    return "$year$divider$month$divider$day";
  }

  String formatTime({String divider = ":"}){
    return "$hour$divider$min$divider$sec";
  }
}
```

Moreover, there is no need to use another package for date-time formatting.